# How to render a component, that contains an opened and not closed tag? React.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I have an objective to make a component, that renders cards with nested ul tags like this: 
[image: needed]
from data like this, that's being passed down with props from a parental component:
[image: data]

For that I set markers at the end of the lines where the nested ul should start, e.g. ":" when the nested ul should open and "." when the nested ul should close. But to make this code work, I need to render **opened, but not closed tags**.

```
let inUl = false;
<div className="cardBody">
        {props.body.map((el, index) => {
          if(el.endsWith(":")){
            inUl = true;
            return <li>{el}<ul>
          } else if(inUl && el.endsWith('.')){
            inUl = false;
            return <li>{el}</li></ul>
          } else {
            return <li>{el}</li>
          }
        })}
  </div>
```

Any help will be greately appreciated, I've a close deadline, and right now I'm literally stuck on the last part of the project - this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Post code, markup, data strings, and other text ***as text***, not as *pictures* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: 1. I don't see any `:` or `.` that explains your code in the data you are showing us, so it's not easy to see what would be the solution, but for what I understand @0xc14m1z's answer sounds good to me. Truth is : there are not any opened tags in React, nor in HTML. If you really think about opened tags, you are probably making a mistake in the way you think your data parsing.

Comment: Probably you're right, maybe I chose the "open/close" tag option, because couldn't find a good way for initial data organisation. Right now trying that with @0xc14m1z's answered variant. Although the code is without any semicolons, a bit hard to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But to make this code work, I need to render opened, but not closed tags.

This is a fundamental misunderstanding of how React works. You use tags in the source code to define elements, which are *objects*. You can't have an opening tag without a closing tag any more than you can have an opening `{` for an object initializer without a closing `}`.

Instead, you have a component that you pass [children](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#children-in-jsx) to, and it renders the children within its component. E.g.:

```
const UnorderedList = props => <ul>{props.children}</ul>;
```

...which is used like this (i.e., in a `render` somewhere):

```
return <UnorderedList><li>...</li><li>...</li></UnorderedList>;
```

Comment: I have thought about this option, but didn't understand what is the difference between **<UnorderedList><li>...</li></UnorderedList>** and just the rendering function that is located in the native ul tag? 
**<ul>data.map(el => <li>{el}</li>)</ul>**

Comment: @Sth - With the above, there isn't. It's just a demonstration of using `children`.

Comment: Sir, can you give me an advise about how to implement that sort of list. I'm trying to do it already 5th hour, have tried lot of different options, even having a **result variable** then appending new **list-items** to it with every iteration, still didn't work out. You seem much experienced, I couldn't express my gratitude if you helped me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't think in term of open or closed tags...

To achieve your result, I would BEFORE reorganize the data in a data structure that could be easily rendered, something like this:

```
const elements = [
    "first ul:",
    "first li",
    "second li",
    "third li.",
    "second ul:",
    "first li",
    "second li",
    "third li.",
    "third ul:",
    "first li",
    "second li",
    "third li."
]

const makeUls = elements => {
    const uls = {}
    let currentUl
    elements.forEach(element => {
        if ( element.endsWith(":") ) {
            uls[element] = []
            currentUl = element
        } else {
            uls[currentUl].push(element)
        }
    })
    return uls
}
```

Calling `makeUls` and giving the flat array, you should have a map like this:

```
Object {
    "first ul:": ["first li", "second li", "third li."],
    "second ul:": ["first li", "second li", "third li."],
    "third ul:": ["first li", "second li", "third li."]
}
```

Once you have this kinda structure, you can easily render everything properly:

```
render() {
    const uls = makeUls(props.body)
    Object.keys(uls).map(ul => (
        <ul>
            { uls[ul].map(li => <li>{ li }</li> }
        </ul>
    ))
}
```

Consider to properly add `key` attribute and everything.

Comment: This code totally doesn't work with my data structure, but I think I got the idea, tho I would appreciate a little bit help with the implementation :)